# How to use gdal_calc.py to process multiple bands

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

I have 2 rasters (raster1 and raster2) with 5 bands for each one.
I want to do some calculation using all bands and write the output to a file with 5 bands.

I try this command :

```
gdal_calc.py -A raster1 -B ratser2 --outfile=result.tiff --calc="A+B"
```

but it generates a wrong output file with only 1 band.

Comment: Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203321/how-to-use-gdal-calc-py-for-multi-band-images. I believe that you must read A and B five times with different names so that you can do your five calc operations.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try:

```
gdal_calc.py -A raster1.tif --A_band=5 -B raster2.tif --B_band=5 --allBands=[A,B] --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"
```

Also check the [following link](https://geohackweek.github.io/raster/04-workingwithrasters/).

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your replay but the option --allBands=[A,B] doesn't work. This option accept only one file.